# Does Golang cache request to both `http/https` version of a URL?

Tags: go

I am currently working with the `net/http` package to make a request by passing the URL from the command line but what I discovered was that :
A cache is made for the request to both `http/https` version of a URL I am testing with

I have tried reading about the package `net/http` Do method
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do

```
httpResponse, err := c.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("An error occurred from the response ", err.Error(), URL)
        os.Exit(100)
    }
```

Scenario 1:
`go run web/webClient/webClient.go https://www.mtsoukalos.eu/`

Result:

```
An error occurred from the response  Get https://www.mtsoukalos.eu/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority https://www.mtsoukalos.eu/
exit status 100
```

Scenario 2:
`go run web/webClient/webClient.go http://www.mtsoukalo.eu/`

```
An error occurred from the response  Get https://www.mtsoukalos.eu/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority http://www.mtsoukalos.eu/
exit status 100
```

The expected result of the URL in Scenario 2 should be `http://www.mtsoukalos.eu/` but I still get `https://www.mtsoukalos.eu/`.

Can you help me understand why it is happening this way?

Comment: Show `curl -v http://www.mtsoukalo.eu/`

Comment: The document says that "Do sends an HTTP request and returns an HTTP response, following policy (such as redirects, cookies, auth) as configured on the client." so maybe the http response is redirecting to https.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I also thought so that the server is making a redirect from http to https.